# Custom InjectableContext cannot differ between two injection points within the same bean in Quarkus

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, quarkus, custom-scope

I try to implement a `@TenantScope` which can be used for stateful beans rather than using a nested map. For this I am implementing a `io.quarkus.arc.InjectableContext`.

I have it working so far, except if I have two injection points of the same type. My implementation for the two `get(...)` methods looks like this::

```
@Override
public <T> T get(Contextual<T> contextual, CreationalContext<T> creationalContext) {
    String tenantId = getTenantIdFromContex();
    Map<String, ContextInstanceHandle<?>> tenantMap = contextualMap.computeIfAbsent(contextual, c -> new HashMap<>());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ContextInstanceHandle<T> contextInstanceHandle =
            (ContextInstanceHandle<T>) tenantMap.computeIfAbsent(tenantId, t -> {
                if (creationalContext == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                T createdInstance = contextual.create(creationalContext);
                return new ContextInstanceHandleImpl<T>(
                        (InjectableBean<T>) contextual, createdInstance, creationalContext);
            });
    return contextInstanceHandle.get();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> T get(Contextual<T> contextual) {
    String tenantId = getTenantIdFromContex();
    if(!contextualMap.containsKey(contextual) || !contextualMap.get(contextual).containsKey(tenantId)){
        return null;
    }
    return ((ContextInstanceHandle<T>) contextualMap.get(contextual).get(tenantId)).get();
}
```

Assume this bean

```
@TenantScoped
class MyTenantScopedQueue(){...}
```

My custom context behaves as expected when I have a single injection point of a `@TenantScoped` type in a bean. Depending on the tenantId of my context, I get the specific instance. As soon as I have two injection points I run into a problem:

```
class MyBean() {

@Inject
MyTenantScopedQueue queue;
@Inject
MyTenantScopedQueue queueForOtherStuff;

...
}
```

It seems that `Contextual<T>` does not hold enough information to differ between this two injection points resulting in having same instance injected twice. How can I implement my `InjectableContext` so I do get different instances for each injection point?

Comment: I have the impression that this is expected. What differentiates the 2 injection points? It seems they differ only in the name of the variable; if so, CDI (and probably ArC) indeed does NOT differentiate between them. I believe this is the text book case for using qualifiers.

Comment: I was already there but then I was bothered by the overhead to define producers for each qualifier (`@Named`). But I guess thats the way to go.

Comment: If you want a new instance for each injection point, you don't need a custom scope and context -- you can just make the bean `@Dependent`. What your context implementation seems to do is a "per-tenant singleton" (which in my opinion is a perfectly reasonable thing to have, just not something that will produce a different instance for each injection point).

Comment: The missing proxy on a dependent bean is an issue fpr my use case. I would need the best from both of the worlds :) I think I just need to befriend, that I need to use qualifiers.
@NikosParaskevopoulos If you want, you can c&p you comment as answer

Comment: In the end, the problem was me, I don't even need to use qualifiers. I went a level to deep. It works as expected with the implementation of the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `@TenantScoped` a [normal scope](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#normal_scope)? If so then the injected `MyTenantScopedQueue` (which is a client proxy) must obtain the active context object first, then call `Context.get()` and finally delegate to the underlying bean instance. And your context implementation must ensure that there is exactly one instance for a given bean *associated with the current thread*.

Now both injection points are satisfied by the same `Bean`. Which means that if you invoke a method upon `queue` and `queueForOtherStuff` from the same thread then both invocations will delegate to the same bean instance.

If the scope is not normal, i.e. not annotated with `@jakarta.enterprise.context.NormalScope` but with `@jakarta.inject.Scope`, then the behavior is undefined (up to you ;-).